# How to add before and after hook for gRPC method call in Java?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I hope to do some logging before and after each method gRPC call (i.e.: on `xxxBlockingStub`).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably to add a logging interceptor. Example outlined here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2145